# RaphaelJS -- vector or not?

Tags: javascript, raphael

I'm trying to place a circle at 50% of the width of the paper using [RaphaelJS](http://raphaeljs.com/), is this possible without first doing the math (.5 * pixel width)? I want to simply be able to place an element at 50% of its container's width, is this even possible with the current Raphael API?

Raphael claims to be able to draw vector graphics, and yet it seems everything in the API is pixel-based. How can you draw a vector image using pixels? That seems 100% contradictory.

Likewise, as I understand vector art, it retains the same dimensions regardless of actual size. Is this not one of the primary reasons to use vector graphics, that it doesn't matter if it's for screen, print or whatever, it will always be the same scale? Thus, I'm further
confused by the need for something like [ScaleRaphael](http://www.shapevent.com/scaleraphael/); just seems like such functionality is part and parcel to creating vector graphics. But, perhaps I just don't understand vector graphics?

It just doesn't seem like an image that is created with absolute pixel dimensions and unable to be resized natively qualifies as a vector image. That, or I'm missing a very large chunk of the API here.

Thanks in advance for any help. I've attempted to post this twice now to the RaphaelJS Google Group, but I guess they are censoring it for whatever reason because I've been waiting for it to appear since last week and still no sign of my posts (although other new posts are showing up).

Comment: Yes, Raphael draws vector graphics. It renders using SVG or VML, both of which are vector languages.

Comment: Just by virtue of using SVG/VML does not mean that it is a true vector graphic...

Comment: And the Raphael API does include a `.scale()` method.

Comment: I don't think that will fulfill my requirements. Scale only deals with the size of the element, no? For instance, I have a paper that is 1000px, so if I need to place a circle at a point 50% of the width of the paper (mid-way), then that would be at 500px. If I resize my browser along the x-axis to say 2000px, the paper will remain the same size and so will the circle. If I then resize the paper to 2000px, the circle will _still_ be at 500px. Calling `.scale()` does nothing for positioning.

Comment: Now maybe if there was a `paper.scale()` method, that would automatically apply scaling to all contained elements, then that would suffice; but, there doesn't appear to be such a method (and thus the reason for ScaleRaphael, I assume).

Comment: You are confusing three things: the meaning of vector graphics, absolute vs relative coordinates and automatic scaling. What you want is relative coordinates (50% of x etc). That has nothing to do with vector graphics. You can create a bitmap library that handles relative coordinates just fine. Vector graphics is something that when scaled up does not suffer from 'jaggies'. To the best of my knowledge most vector formats like SVG, PDF, VML and AI deal exclusively with absolute coordinates. I only know of one format that can do relative coordinates: PS but only because it is Turing Complete.

Comment: Automatic scaling also does not have anything to do with vector graphics. You can implement automatic scaling for bitmaps in CSS just fine.

Comment: Everything would be ok if the "paper" was considered a graphic, but as-is, I think it's simply a level of misdirection because I cannot see any value that it adds; it's merely a container for actual graphics. I think that's where the problem lies, and as such, I don't quite understand why there is even a notion of "paper". If the paper (and it's contents) were all considered the same 'graphic', then scaling the paper would appropriately scale the rest of the elements, but that's not the case...

Comment: So, I wonder if I created a pseudo-paper and then put my items in that, if I would be able to achieve what I'm looking for.

Comment: I fail to see how automatic scaling doesn't relate to vector art, every time that I've dealt with vector graphics in the past they have all resized gracefully while retaining the proper dimensions. That's pretty much the only reason I've used vector art, because it scales...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using pixel values to define shape positions/dimensions does not make it a non-vector shape. Take for instance Adobe Illustrator - this is a vector product and yet you can still see that the properties for each object shows the positions and dimensions is pixels.

A basic explanation of vector graphics would be like this, taking a rectangle as an example:

> A vector rectangle will have a number of properties such as x, y,
>   width and height. These properties can be specified in pixels. The
>   difference with vector (as opposed to raster) is that these pixel
>   properties are only used to determine how the shape is drawn. So when
>   the display is rendered (refreshed) the "system" can redrawn the shape
>   using the same properties without effecting the quality of the resize.
>
> A raster image however will hold a lot more information (i.e. the
>   exact value of each pixel used to form the shape/rectangle)

If the word "pixel" makes you think it is contradictory, just remeber everything on a computer screen is rendered in pixels. Even vector graphics have to be converted to "raster" as some point in the graphics pipeline.

If you are worried about having to use a calculation (0.5 * width) then just remember that something has to do that calculation, and personally I would happily handle this simple step myself.

After all that, you should just calculate size and position in pixels based on the size of your "paper" element and feed those values in Raphael for creating the shape.